# MySql - Insert new rows based on current table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm looking to select rows from a table, then use the output to insert new rows **into the same table**.

This is for the `wp_postmeta` table in Wordpress, and the query looks like:

```
SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_program_id'
```

What I would like to do is insert a new `meta_key` called `_program_current_id` which I'll use to check for change of values.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
  VALUES (
      (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_program_id'),
      '_program_current_id',
      (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_program_id')
  );
```

However, this is not working as the same table can't be specified twice and probably other errors. Thoughts?

Comment: Since you are using the same `WHERE` clause, you can simply select both columns together: `SELECT post_id, meta_value  FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_program_id'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the `VALUES` keyword.

There's two forms of INSERT statement:

```
INSERT ... VALUES ( ... )
```

and

```
INSERT ... SELECT ...
```

We use the VALUES form when there's a fixed number of rows we want to insert; usually one row. (A MySQL extension allows for insert of multiple rows, separating the tuples with commas...  `INSERT ... VALUES ('row1',...), ('row2,...), ...`

When the number of rows is dynamic, generated from a `SELECT` statement, we use the `INSERT ... SELECT` form which does not have the `VALUES` keyword.

Reference:   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

---

Looks like we are after something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO wp_postmeta
 ( post_id
 , meta_key
 , meta_value
 )

 SELECT s.post_id                AS post_id
      , '_program_current_id'    AS meta_key
      , s.meta_value             AS meta_value
   FROM wp_postmeta s
  WHERE s.meta_key = '_program_id'
```

Run just the `SELECT` part (just a SELECT statement) to verify the results. Verify that those are the rows we want to insert. Then we can run the `INSERT ... SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a temp table to store the output values you want and then insert them after

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
 OUTPUT INSERTED.post_id , INSERTED.meta_key , INSERTED.meta_value INTO #temp_output 
 SELECT post_id , meta_key , meta_value 
 FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_program_id')

INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ( post_id , meta_key , meta_value ) 
 SELECT TOP 1 post_id , meta_key , meta_value 
 FROM #temp_output
 ORDER BY meta_key DESC ;
```

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: This syntax looks like Transact-SQL i.e. Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL